# I want to simulate a mouse click on osx from python at an application windown RELATIVE location

Tags: python, macos, user-interface

I have spend about 5 hours trying to find an OSX / PYTHON solution for generating mouse clicks.

It is preferable that this solution does not require download of third party utilities (like cliclick).  and it is critical that the solution is making mouse clicks that are relative to a specific application window, or to the application in focus.

I expect that applescript, Tkinter, quartz graphics libraries, or other libraries like xuWidgets could be invoked on a generic OSX box without downloads, but try as I might, I cannot find any full solutions to this simple problem.

any pointers would be great!

Comment: Look into this [library](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput) here.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi  thanks for the pointer, but when I looked at the source code, it appeared that it only supported mouse clicks in absolute screen coordinates.  Is there code to xlate into application window specfic coordinates somewhere I am missing?